# Counting UTF8 characters with Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I've been preparing a simple example of Python script for my students and I found to struggle to solve following issue.
I am using `utf8` coding because I want them to use Polish characters, e.g.
Ł, ą, ś. Now, the script is supposed to take name from the user and print it
in the rectangular made of *. So this is what I want to show  them:

```
imie=raw_input('Podaj swoje imię: ') #Give your name

dl=len(imie)

print '*'*(dl + 4)
print '*' + ' '*(dl + 2) + '*'
print '* ' + imie + ' *'
print '*' + ' '*(dl + 2) + '*'
print '*'*(dl + 4)
```

The issue is that, for name such as `Antoś Mąka`, the `dl` variable value should be 11, but it is 13, because ś and ą signs are calculated as two.
Is it possible to force `len()` function to calculate it as 1?

Comment: python 3 does not have these problems, that you encounter in python2. All strings are unicode in python3, and len works just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the data from utf8 into a unicode object. Then get the len of the unicode.

```
imie=raw_input('Podaj swoje imię: ').decode('utf8') #Give your name
dl=len(imie)
print dl
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.* use `decode`:

```
dl=len(imie.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding to `"utf-8"` it would be better to use `sys.stdin.encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `str` when you should be using `unicode`

```
imie = unicode(raw_input('....').decode('utf-8'))
```